# User YACP harassing me again

Tags: support

I have asked for help on this before. User YACP is posting harassing comments on answers I give to questions and now randomly picking questions to mock and insult me in

[Is there a geometric realization of Quaternion group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317880/is-there-a-geometric-realization-of-quaternion-group#comment691419_317880)

I think you need to discourage this obnoxious behavior or it will make the site a worse and worse place

this is where it happened before but the comments are all deleted now so you cant see anything unless you're a mod I think [Quintic polynomial with Galois Group $A_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/quintic-polynomial-with-galois-group-a-5)

Comment: Better to flag for moderator attention than to post here. There's nothing the rest of us could do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, it's not a good idea documenting it so when it happens again and again people actually believe me instead of having forgotten or sweeping it under the rug? I did flag it too of course.

Comment: Not much point "documenting" something by referring to comments we can't see.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, moderators

Answer (score 14):

The best way to deal with such a situation is to flag all offensive or inappropriate comments,  six flags will automatically delete them. If there is a pattern of problematic user behaviour, you should also use a custom moderator flag (not on a comment) to make the moderators aware of the problem. The comment flags are not sufficient for that, as they can be resolved by the community and the moderators might never see them.

Moderators can see a list of deleted comments by a specific user (user profile -> mod -> info -> comments), so there is no need to document them all on meta. Just pointing out a few examples and explaining that there are more of those comments in your flag should be sufficient.

Comment: They had six flags over Texas, and it never got deleted.

Comment: Texas is exceptional! Let me know if you ever want to visit, @GerryMyerson.

Comment: @The, I lived in Austin, 1985-87. Don't mess with Texas!